# Table pivot / Burt Table - Python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I would like create a pivot table / Burt table for ACM model. But, i didn't create the table with sum row and sum columns.

This my input :

[image]
And my output :

[image]

```
data = np.array([['Taille++', 'Veloc++', 'Affec+'],
['Taille-', 'Veloc-', 'Affec-'],
['Taille++', 'Veloc++', 'Affec+'],
['Taille+', 'Veloc+', 'Affec+'],
['Taille-', 'Veloc-', 'Affec+'],
['Taille++', 'Veloc-', 'Affec-'],
['Taille-', 'Veloc+', 'Affec+'],
['Taille+', 'Veloc+', 'Affec+']], dtype=object)

columns = ['Chien','Velocite', 'Affection']

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns)
```

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks you  !!

Comment: I've linked a very godo q&a on pivots in pandas that should cover your question.

Comment: Not really, because my problem is than the name columns and index must have the same name..

Comment: dont post images of data. copy and paste it in your question

Comment: please add your data as text

Comment: Yes, i'm doing this